# getstring() from a call without extend activity

Tags: android, class, android-activity, getstring

I have a problem with a simple class that contains information that I will like to call from another class. For example here is the class `Util` which contains the info:

```
public class Util{

public ArrayList<RecetaBean> getRellenas() {
    ArrayList<RecetaBean> MiLista = new ArrayList<RecetaBean>();

    RecetaBean receta1 = new RecetaBean();
    String ingrediente1[] = {         getString(R.string.app_name),getString(R.string.app_name),
    };
    receta1.setIngredientesLista(ingrediente1);

    MiLista.add(receta1);
    MiLista.add(receta1);
    MiLista.add(receta1);


    return MiLista;
}   
  }
```

Then in another class I get the Items calling like this:

```
    Util u = new Util();
    ArrayList<RecetaBean> Recetas = u.getRellenas();
```

So, I have a execution problem in the class `Util` with the `GETSTRING`, because I would like to get a different string (because of different languages). The way to quit the error is to extend the class `Util` from `Activity`, but `Util` is not an `Activity`! And if I extend from `Activity`, the app crash.

Comment: Pass ``Util`` constructor a reference to your Activity, or ``Context``  to be more precise. From ``Context`` you can access ``getString`` method and localised strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is Define a Context in the Method .

and call it like this;

```
Util u = new Util();
ArrayList<RecetaBean> Recetas = u.getRellenas(this);
```

and you the context in you Methods like this:

```
public ArrayList<RecetaBean> getRellenas(Context con) {
    ArrayList<RecetaBean> MiLista = new ArrayList<RecetaBean>();

    RecetaBean receta1 = new RecetaBean();
    String ingrediente1[] = {         con.getString(R.string.app_name), con.getString(R.string.app_name),
    };
    receta1.setIngredientesLista(ingrediente1);

    MiLista.add(receta1);
    MiLista.add(receta1);
    MiLista.add(receta1);


    return MiLista;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you thought about using a string array? It would be so much simpler than what you are trying to do.

I do not think that your concerns about language change are justified, in terms of the overall user experience.